# Android Studio project doesn't run on devices

Tags: android-studio, apk

Currently I'm making some android applications by Android studio.
My application working on emulator so fine but when I generate apk file for install on android devices any project doesn't run and they crash.
I tired to search for find answer or suggestion for fin this problem but I didn't find anything.
Can you tell me how can I fix this problem?

Comment: what about logcat? what it produces?

Comment: apk generate fine without any error. when I install apk file in devices It has crash

Comment: if app crashes there is a reason in logcat. Can you provide output?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I install apk on device, phone does not connect to computer then I can't see log cat.

Comment: In this case this question is too broad.